# Problems with creating new local server

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have a problem with creating a new server in PgAdmin 4. I have server with the port 5432 as standard. Now I am trying to create a new server with port 5433. When I try to create the server I get the error: 
[image]

I don't now how to fix. The server is running on "localhost", but I don't now how to connect the TCP/IP on port 5433.

Thx for you help.

Comment: Well, **do** you have another instance of Postgres running that uses 5433?

Comment: Not as far as I now. I recently restored/formatted my computer to fabric settings. After that I did install Postgres weith the port 5433. But due to problems I had to remove it and reinstall with port 5432. 

So what I am guessing from you comment, it is this previously postgres, which is causing the problem? And do you now how to fix it?

Comment: If you don't have an instance running on port 5433, then why do you expect to be able to connect to it? If your running Postgres listens on 5432 then use that port.

Comment: The problem is that I have a lot of backups from before i formatted, which is running on 5433. That is why I need that port too.

Comment: If you want a second instance running on 5433 you need to [initialize](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) a new [database cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-concepts.html) or just restore the backups to the instance running on 5432